# Run a background process permanently on a node through a script on Jenkins and let Jenkins build successfully

Tags: jenkins

I am running a background process through a script , this script is invoked when Jenkin starts building. However, the jenkins build gets stuck and on looking at the console it seems it is running the process and waits for it to complete.

This process will never complete, consider this as a server listening to its client.Every build I trigger kills the server process and restarts the process, so I am perfectly handling that scenario.

Is there any way , I can build jenkins successfully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact details depend on your operating system (which you did not tell), but the Jenkins wiki has a page about this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

Comment: This seems near impossible to do with Jenkins running on windows does anyone have a solution? I've now spent an entire day on this, it just shows how utterly incapable windows is as a real server

Comment: @wired00 Maybe a little bit late but check [nssm](https://nssm.cc/). Great for creating, starting and stoping services in windows

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can do in order you free a Jenkins thread.

What you can do is to execute a bash script through a ssh connection and send it to the background while saving the pid of the process somewhere so you can make checks further.

The format of the command would be:

```
ssh -n _hostname_ "_commands_ & echo \$! > \"_path_to_pid_file_\"" &
```

Example with a never-ending program:

```
ssh -n myhost.domain.com "tail -f /var/log/my.log & echo \$! > \"$WORKSPACE/pid\"" &
```

This example will spawn the tail process listening forever for new changes in the /var/log/my.log file and store its pid in the $WORKSPACE/pid file.

When executed from a Jenkins job the ssh process will exit immediately while the commands sent to the background will remain in execution in the specified host.

I do this in order to maintain always one of the services I run in my build farm in-sync with the latest code modification of it in the repository.
Just have a job that ssh' into the target machine and then kill the process, update the service and re-launches it.

This could be a bit cumbersome but it works great!