# How to continue the command / bat file running from Jenkins pipeline, even after the steps completes?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**So, here's what I want to achieve:**

1. I have to start a server using a bat/sh file from Jenkins pipeline.
2. This step in the pipeline, opens a new console in the background (using START in Win and '&' in Linux)
3. And keeps a check on, whether the server has started or not.
4. Once the server starts, this step is completed and the pipeline closes.

**ISSUE:** When the pipeline closes, it takes the server down with itself.

I assume the reason must be: it also closes the background console, which was opened by it when this step finishes.

**Question:** How to keep the bat/sh file running in Win/Linux even after the pipeline step that started it, gets closed.

Comment: Could you share the script you are using?

Comment: Question [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22703929/598141) and [answered](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=1835010#content/view/1835010) or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/502593/starting-a-forever-process-in-a-jenkins-build-step)